# how to compare timestamps

Tags: jquery, timestamp

I have looked on this forum and found some simmiliar posts about converting timestamps with jQuery.
But i havent found once that fixes my problem.

Im working on a webapplication, in combination with Jquery Mobile.
In this webapp im showing some twitter feeds: image from and message. Now im trying to get the date in there also.

Wehn im retreiving the date from the json its like this:

```
Tue, 05 Jun 2012 13:25:06 +0000
```

now i want to compare this date with the current date to calculate the time past. 
This because i want to say: 1 second ago, 2 min ago 1 hour ago etc.

can someone tell me how i can compare the current date with the twitter date?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare timestamp in javascript like this .

```
var input_date = new Date('Tue, 05 Jun 2012 13:25:06 +0000').getTime();
var curr_date = new Date().getTime();
if(input_date > curr_date){
  alert("greater");    
}else{
  alert('small');
}
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgZNH/1/)

​But as per your requirement, you want to show time like '1 min ago','1 hour ago','2 days ago', You can use ***jquery timeago plugin*** instead of doing javascrpt calculations. Please see [this plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/), it'll fulfill your needs.

Comment: +1 Don't re-make something just for the sake of it, particularly when it's already been done. If the whole plugin is overkill for your needs, then strip the relevant parts out of it and integrate it into your own stuff. More often than not, there will be edge cases handled in open-source projects that you might otherwise miss catering for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var twitterDate = new Date("Tue, 05 Jun 2012 13:25:06 +0000").getTime(),
    now = new Date().getTime();

if (twitterDate > now) {
    alert('Future')
} else {
    alert('Past');
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/151/)**

> The value returned by the getTime method is the number of milliseconds
>   since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Read about **[.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)**

And to get Date difference you can you following method:

```
function getDateDiff(twitterDate, interval) { // interval means unit,
    // in which you want the result
    var second = 1000,
        minute = second * 60,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24,
        week = day * 7;
    date1 = new Date(twitterDate).getTime();
    date2 = new Date().getTime();
    var timediff = date2 - date1;
    if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
    switch (interval) {
    case "years":
        return date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear() + ' years ago.';
    case "months":
        return ((date2.getFullYear() * 12 + date2.getMonth()) - (date1.getFullYear() * 12 + date1.getMonth())) + ' months ago.';
    case "weeks":
        return Math.floor(timediff / week) + ' weeks ago.';
    case "days":
        return Math.floor(timediff / day) + ' days ago.';
    case "hours":
        return Math.floor(timediff / hour) + ' hours ago.';
    case "minutes":
        return Math.floor(timediff / minute) + ' minutes ago.';
    case "seconds":
        return Math.floor(timediff / second) + ' seconds ago.';
    default:
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
getDateDiff("Tue, 05 Jun 2012 13:25:06 +0000", "seconds");
```

Comment: first thank you i got it almost working but got one more problem. when i try to put it in a case switch i cant seem to get it work. im using case switch to determine how much time has past to show the message. 1 min ago etc